# Stopping my while loop with a confirm box

Tags: javascript, while-loop

Here is my code.  I can't figure out how to stop this loop when the use selects "cancel" from the window.confirm box

I'm really rusty and never delved that deep into programming anywho lol - I am used to C++ so I'm not sure if there just might be a better function to call other than window.confirm.

code:

```
alert( "1 = 10, 2 = 20, 3 = 30, 4 = 40, 5 = 50" );

var myArray = [0, 10, 20, 30, 40, 50];
var askAgain = true;
var pickOne;
var pickTwo;
var answer;
var numOne;
var numTwo;

while (askAgain = true){

    numOne = prompt( "Select a number by entering the associated slot #:");
    numTwo = prompt( "Select a number to be added to the first number by            

        entering the associated slot #:" );

    pickOne = myArray[numOne];
    pickTwo = myArray[numTwo];

    pickOne.Number;
    pickTwo.Number;

    answer = pickOne + pickTwo;

    alert("You picked " + pickOne + " and " + pickTwo + ", combined they equal: "       

        + answer);

    window.confirm( "Would you like to go again?" );
    if (confirm == true){
        askAgain = true;
    } else {
        askAgain = false;
    }
}
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Where is the value for `confirm` being assigned? Also, you should be able to merge the `askAgain` and `confirm` variables into a single variable.

Comment: @DaveJarvis It's not, at least not in the code shown here... :)

Answer (score 5):

Small error in your code:

```
while (askAgain = true){
```

Should be:

```
while (askAgain == true){
```

= assigns a value
== checks if they are equal

another issue is you need to assign confirm like this:

```
var confirm = window.confirm( "Would you like to go again?" );
```

Comment: Thank you so much!

I can't believe I forgot that :(

Comment: No worries, happens to everyone.

Comment: Hrm, actually may have gotten a little ahead of myself.  After implimenting the new code, after clicking OK, the loop ends.

Adding the == to the while loops ends the loop.  Also, defining confirm variable will allow my first alert to popup, but nothing after the fact.